# LEFT OUTER JOIN with CubeJs

Tags: javascript, postgresql, cube.js

I'm trying to achieve this query in CubeJS which does a LEFT OUTER JOIN with itself.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT EC."accId")
FROM public."orders" EC 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN public."orders" NC
    ON NC."accId" = EC."accId" 
    AND NC."isFirstOutletTransaction" = true
    AND NC."occurredAt" > '2020-02-01'
    AND NC."occurredAt" < '2020-03-01'
WHERE EC."occurredAt" > '2020-02-01' 
AND EC."occurredAt" < '2020-03-01' 
AND EC."isFirstOutletTransaction"=false 
AND NC."accId" is null;
```

I'm stuck on how to express this in the CubeJS schema. Would appreciate the help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create one cube called e.g. "FirstOutletTransatction" with the appropriate condition:

`sql: 'select * from public."orders" NC where NC."isFirstOutletTransaction" = true'`

then define the other cube e.g. "NonFirstOutletTransatction" like:

`sql: 'select * from public."orders" NC where NC."isFirstOutletTransaction" = false'`

Define the relation of the two cubes in their joins and add `"occurredAt"` either as time dimension or in the query as a condition.